# jQuery event ended handling works with bind but not on

Tags: jquery, events

I'm trying to catch the "end" event of a video with jQuery 1.10

```
$('#hvid').on('ended', function() {
    window.console && console.log('ended');
});
```

where `#hvid` is the "id" of the `<video>` element.  This doesn't work and gives me an 'undefined is not a function' error. Same error if I use the 'delegated' version of "on", too.

But, if I use "bind" instead of "on", it works:

```
$('#hvid').bind('ended', function() {
    window.console && console.log('ended');
});
```

I understand that "bind" is deprecated so it's always preferred to use "on". Any obvious reason why "on" should not work?

Comment: Since `bind` just calls `on`, there's no way that one will work and the other won't. Unless you're using an old version of jQuery that doesn't have `on`.

Comment: I'm using 1.10 as I said.  I think bind was deprecated in 1.7?

Comment: Upgraded to 1.11.2 jquery and still the same - bind works, on doesn't

Comment: Is it possible you're loading multiple copies of jQuery, and one of them is older than 1.7?

Comment: What does `alert($().jquery);` show?

Comment: @Barmar You nailed it!  When I alerted the version number it came up with 1.3.2.  I tracked it down to a piece of garbage booking engine script that must also load Jquery.  Explains everything, thanks for your help.